# Primefaces 6. ContextMenu with nodeType wrong behaviour with horizontal Tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an application (JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.1) working in production (1+ year). Now I'm upgrading that app to Primefaces 6.0, but have found an issue with the context menu of an horizontal tree. When pressing right mouse button over a node, it shows the wrong contextMenu (using nodeType) also the action doesn't get the node selected as in PF 5.1. Changing the tree orientation to vertical works as expected.
I've created a test project and noticed the same behaviour.
Sample page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText id="seleccion" value="Valor seleccionado: #{testController.seleccionado.data}"/>
            <p:tree id="arbol" orientation="horizontal" value="#{testController.raiz}" var="nodo" selectionMode="single" selection="#{testController.seleccionado}">
                <p:treeNode type="carpeta" expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                    #{nodo}
                </p:treeNode>
                <p:treeNode type="hoja">
                    #{nodo}
                </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
            <p:contextMenu for="arbol" nodeType="carpeta">
                <p:menuitem value="Ver carpeta" update="seleccion"/>
            </p:contextMenu>
            <p:contextMenu for="arbol" nodeType="hoja">
                <p:menuitem value="Ver hoja" update="seleccion"/>
            </p:contextMenu>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Sample bean:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;

@Named(value = "testController")
@ViewScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7028608421091861830L;

    private TreeNode raiz;
    private TreeNode seleccionado;

    public TreeNode getRaiz() {
        return raiz;
    }

    public void setRaiz(TreeNode raiz) {
        this.raiz = raiz;
    }

    public TreeNode getSeleccionado() {
        return seleccionado;
    }

    public void setSeleccionado(TreeNode seleccionado) {
        this.seleccionado = seleccionado;
    }

    public TestController() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void crearArbol() {
        raiz = new DefaultTreeNode("carpeta", "Origen", null);
        TreeNode alfa = new DefaultTreeNode("carpeta", "Alfa", raiz);
        TreeNode beta = new DefaultTreeNode("carpeta", "Beta", raiz);
        new DefaultTreeNode("hoja", 1, alfa);
        new DefaultTreeNode("hoja", 2, alfa);
        new DefaultTreeNode("hoja", 3, beta);
        new DefaultTreeNode("hoja", 4, beta);
    }

}
```

Tested same behaviour in Chrome and Firefox, using both wildlfy 8.2.1 and 10.0.0.
Someone knows a workaround? I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to change the place where the contextMenu is made i mean to include it in your tree ?!?

Comment: Tried your suggestion, it doesn't work. Get the following exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.component.contextmenu.ContextMenu cannot be cast to org.primefaces.component.tree.UITreeNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved in PF 6.0.13 (tested). https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1920

Thanks.